# python: fast way to translate a list of a frequency map

Tags: python, python-2.7

a list of ["A","A","A","B","B","B"]

to dictionary of
{'A': 3,
 'B': 3}

I've done something like below but i feel like there is a faster/shorter way of doing it?

```
frequencyMap = dict()
letters = ["A","A","A","B","B","B"]

for letter in letters:
    if letter not in frequencyMap:
        frequencyMap[letter] = 0
    frequencyMap[letter] += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.7 (or newer), you can use collections.Counter

collections.Counter()

A counter is a container that stores elements as dictionary keys, and their counts are stored as dictionary values.

```
import collections
a = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5]
counter=collections.Counter(a)
print(counter)
# Counter({1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 2, 5: 2, 4: 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

print(Counter(["A","A","A","B","B","B"]))
```